# Why aren't ModLoader's decompiled files showing up?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding, eclipse

I want to start making a Minecraft 1.6.4 mod, but have this trouble with ModLoader:

I've run the `decompile.bat` batch file, but when opening the `eclipse` folder, the `bin` folder is empty. The batch file ran fine with no errors, and `/src/minecraft/net/minecraft` contains many decompiled java files, but no modloader files like `BaseMod.java`.

If I open this folder with Eclipse, the package explorer menu stays empty.

What's happening here?

Comment: This question is probably more fitting for http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mr This seems to be about *making* a modification, which [is on-topic here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here). *Using* a modification [would indeed be for Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here).

Comment: @Mr.Beast I posted it there at first, and it got closed for being off topic. Someone suggested I post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCP decompiler should give you a warning saying that the jar is modded and may behave in ways that were unexpected, this is not just one of those errors you ignore and brush off, it is there for a reason. MCP only contains mappings for the obfuscated minecraft code, and when you throw extra files into the mix (such as modloader) it tends to behave erratically. I would suggest using an easier and more capable alternative, the Minecraft Forge project. It's easy to use and they now have an automated build and update system, making it more convenient than ever, I myself have made a few tutorials on how to get the forge workspace up and running [here](http://calcuprocessing.com/index.php?post=20). that being said, if you still want to continue using ModLoader, here are some debugging tips to make sure that you decompile correctly.

- Make sure the jar you provide MCP with is modded
- Make sure that the version of ModLoader is correct for that minecraft version
- Make sure you import the project into eclipse instead of just adding the files, to ensure  you are seeing all of the decompiled project.

Happy Modding!

Comment: Cheers, there was no warning but i will definitely check out the minecraft forge, modloader seems so goddamn difficult. I only used it because of a tutorial I found on the minecraft forums

Comment: Yeah, another thing to look at are Wuppy's tutorials for minecraft forge, he has some really good ones

Comment: Your tutorials helped a great deal, and now I have it all set up. I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: No problem, if you need any more help, feel free to shoot me an email: officialtoxicdub@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Your question is phrased unclearly, but I think this is what you mean:

"I have the correct files in Eclipse that are decompiled, but they dont show up!!!".

This is because Eclipse does not just show any random file in the directory. You must add the classes in. If you add a class that already exists (e.g. your decompiled modloader code), then it will automatically use the class file already there.

I do not have as much experience with ModLoader. I program minecraft server plugins, not minecraft client mods, but I hope that this has helped.